# Tracking of Common Services in AWS using X-ray

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-xray

I have multiple Lambdas and each of them either invoke another lambda or a
rest API or a dynamoDB or S3 etc .

Example :

- HotelBooking
- FlighBooking

These invoke the common services like

- BookingService
- InvoiceService

I need to track which application i.e Flight Booking / HotelBooking is invoking the booking service and how many times / how much CPU etc

Is this possible through X-Ray in AWS or any other better ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I believe annotation is the best way for the above problem

So we need to add an annotation in NodeJS

```js
            AWSXRay.captureFunc('annotations', (subsegment) => {
                subsegment.addAnnotation('application', "BookingService");
            });
```

Annotations are indexed and can be used to filter too
using an expression like this annotation.= "BookingService"

more Info : 
X-ray merges segments, Subsegments to traces so the annotation at subsegment level is enough for filtering the traces

Answer (score -1):

AWS Xray can help you to trace downstream calls made by lambda application in a form of segments and subsegments in order to give you the over all view of your application. I think AWS Xray can help you in your use case and also you will be able to trace Dynamodb, S3 or RestAPI calls that your lambda is making and able to identify which application (in your case Flight Booking / HotelBooking) is invoking the service (booking service). Though you might not see performance numbers (e.g. memory and CPU usage) but you will be able to trace exceptions inside your application.

Comment: I am aware of X-Ray but I want to know how to track who is invoking common services

Comment: Services are broken down into segments. When using X-Ray, you generally preconfigure the segment name to be the particular service it represents. We have supported web frameworks depending on the language you are using. In Java for example, we support Spring Boot and Servlets, where the segment name is predefined as your service name. In your case, you may name the segment for the particular service to be "BookingService" or "InvoiceService". X-Ray will keep track of any exceptions, latencies, and resource metadata (if you're making a downstream call).

Comment: @ChanChiemJefferySaeteurn So you mean to say I can filter the downstream calls based on the Source Service which is making calls,

Just another question, so what If I make calls to these common services from the Browser and I still want to know the call are made from BookingHotel Page or Booking Flight page ?